# Pass SecurityException through multiple hops of WCF services

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, authorization

I've got an ASP.NET MVC/WebApi application that acts as a WCF client. My WCF services are authorizing via `ClaimsPrincipalPermission` and additionally throw a `SecurityException` if the combination of the current user and the data does not match (e.g. user is trying to access data from other user).

I catch this as a `SecurityAccessDeniedException` in my filters and return status code 403.

This however only works for communication that involves a single hop. If the service itself communicates with yet another service, then the `SecurityAccessDeniedException` gets turned into a `FaultException` before it reaches the web application.

Example flow:

```
Web client --> Service A [SecurityException] --> [SecurityAccessDeniedException] Web

Web client --> Service A --> Service B [SecurityException] 
  --> [SecurityAccessDeniedException] Service A [FaultException] --> [FaultException] Web
```

I tried implementing an `IErrorHandler` that handles the `SecurityAccessDeniedException` but I cannot just throw a `SecurityException` there.

What are my options to propagate the `SecurityException` up to the Web client?

Alternatively: how can I construct a message in my error handler, which the client then correctly interprets as a `SecurityAccessDeniedException`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now using an `IErrorHandler` which generates a corresponding `FaultException`. On the caller, this generates yet another `SecurityAccessDeniedException`, which I could then handle with the same `IErrorHandler` etc.

```
public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message message)
{
    if (error is SecurityAccessDeniedException)
    {
        var code = FaultCode.CreateSenderFaultCode(
            "FailedAuthentication",
            "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");

        var faultText = new FaultReasonText(error.Message, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

        var faultException = new FaultException(new FaultReason(faultText), code);
        MessageFault messageFault = faultException.CreateMessageFault();
        message = Message.CreateMessage(version, messageFault, "FailedAuthentication"); // the last parameter might not be semantically correct...
    }
}
```

I got this idea by looking at http://leastprivilege.com/2007/11/01/wcf-and-securityaccessdeniedexception/